# Display not adjusts it self with ssh connected to a container in linux server after i resize the font size in item2

Tags: linux, ssh

### Problem description:

I was using ssh connecting to a linux server and use `docker exec -u root -it container-name bash` to login into the container with item2. The display failed to resize itself after I changed the font size.
And it looks like below:
[image]

### Things tried:

1. Change the setting in the server

```
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

2. Change some configuration of item2 like
   preferences -> advanced -> Terminal windows resize smoothly to yes

### Expected result:

After i resize the font, i can get below display with full screen:
[image]

### Related question:

1. What side decide the problem, ssh client side or ssh server side?

Comment: imho this is normal as the default Terminal size has a fixed value and will not update by itself.